# Router capable for being OpenVPN client

Tags: router, vpn

I need to have a router with OpenVPN client inside. To have it to connect to remote OpenVPN server and share this connection. Is it possible?

Comment: Sharing the openvpn connection is just a matter of sharing the config file

Comment: Router should be capable to read this file or accept it's content in appropriate web form.